# Generate token based on file absolute path

Tags: java, hash, token, filenames, filepath

I have a Java Spring website and I need to allow access to some resources that are in a shared drive via an URL with a token like:

localhost/MyApp/resources/download&token=nFVqE5Xi6SBugGrI4q

Now, to avoid generating an hash and storing it in a database, I want to be able to easily decrypt the token so it becomes the path of the file:

Folder1/Subfolder2/filename.mp4

I've seen that I should be able to do it with DES and AES, but it seems a bit overkill and the token isn't really that elegant... Base64 isn't an option either, as it is really easy to revert.

What's the most elegant way of handling this?

Comment: you'd still have to b64-encode your aes/des stuff anyways, since the raw binary cyphertext can/will naturally contain url-metacharacters. b64 isn't encryption, anyways, and never will be. it's an encoding format. if b64 is encryption, then so's ascii, utf, iso8859, etc...

Comment: Well, you need encryption regardless, so why not use a good, proven algorithm that has no public known attacks like AES?

Comment: @MarcB yeah I know, but I've seen examples where base64 was used.
Augusto I might just do that. I already use Jasypt with Hibernate, I'll see if I can encrypt\decrypt text with it.

Thanks all.